# Cumulative over column other than the one used for the binning

Tags: r, count

imagine to have a 2 columns  (X,Y) file, with X  from 0 to 1 and Y from -1 to 1.

What I want to create is a new file with 3 columns (Z,cnt, cnt_neg) such that for each value of

```
Z <- seq(from=0,to=0.2,by=0.001)
cnt = number of cases for  (X>Z[i])
cnt_neg = number of cases for  (X>Z[i] && Y<0)
```

here a subsample of the data

```
 X                          Y

 0.000000e+00            0.000000000

 6.776256e-05           -0.434395460

 6.345427e-03            0.006335658

 7.018170e-03           -0.005483665

 1.746639e-02            0.017460916

 1.424365e-01            0.138704340
```

Practically these are 2 cumulative distributions; a standard one and one done over a column other than the one used for the binning.
I can make it working with a double loop like other languages, but I really want to work with R.

Among the various attempts there is:

```
for(i in 1:length(Z)){ 
     cnt[i]<-sum(rle(X>Z[i])$lengths)
     cnt_neg[i]<-sum(rle(X>Z[i] && Y<0)$lengths)
     cnt[i]=cnt[i]+1
     cnt_neg[i]=cnt_neg[i]+1
}
```

but the output is correct only for the first raw (0, 5, 2) but for the rest of the rows all remain the same except the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided we combine `X` & `Y` in  a `data.frame`, we can use `dplyr` to solve it, if I understood what you are after:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(X, Y)

df %>% 
    mutate(bin = cut(X, 
                     seq(from=0,to=0.2,by=0.001), 
                     labels = F, 
                     right = T,
                     include.lowest = F),
           bin = ifelse(is.na(bin), 0, bin)
           ) %>% 
    group_by(bin) %>% 
    summarise(cnt = n(), cnt_neg = sum(Y < 0)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(bin = bin * .001, cnt = sum(cnt) - cumsum(cnt), cnt_neg = sum(cnt_neg) - cumsum(cnt_neg)) %>% 
    as.data.frame

#     bin cnt cnt_neg
# 1 0.000   5       2
# 2 0.001   4       1
# 3 0.007   3       1
# 4 0.008   2       0
# 5 0.018   1       0
# 6 0.143   0       0
```

1. Create a new variable `bin`, with the interval each X value belongs to
2. Group by it
3. Count how many values are in the interval and how many Y are negative
4. Ungroup
5. Calculate the inverse `cumsum`

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to  help.
the output should be like

0 5 2

Comment: uhm, It is.. for the first row: bin = 0, cnt = 5, cnt_neg = 2. For the second row: bin = 0.001, cnt = 4, cnt_neg = 1

Comment: Hi ,sorry, my message was incomplete.
Yes! It works as I wanted it. I can follow what you have done, but it is way above my skills. Thanks!!
MM

Comment: Have a look at https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html for dplyr and `?cut` for that part. Pls consider upvote and accepting the answer